# Why would an employer offer remote work only from certain places?

Tags: software-industry, job-search, united-states, telecommute

I was browsing job opportunities for Front End Web Developer positions when I found one that looked promising and offered remote work. However, when reading through the job offer on their website I found that the remote work is only offered in certain locations:

> The majority of our team is remote, and we offer remote work from California, Texas, Arkansas, Ohio, or Illinois

It's worth noting that they offer relocation to their main headquarters in Connecticut, so it's not like they only offer remote work to places close to the HQ.

Why would a company specify specific locations to work remote at a job that can seemingly be done anywhere? Is it just company policy or is there some sort of legal/licensing issues that they've only completed in those states? Or perhaps I'm just reading it wrong and that's just the locations their current remote employees work.

I'm only asking because I want to know if it's worth cleaning up my resume and going through the application process in hopes they allow it or if it's likely set in stone.

Comment: I suspect it is based on taxation and possibly some liability laws.   I am not a CPA nor lawyer.

Comment: Or, on a more global scale, preferred timezones and the amount of paperwork required.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Tax laws.  In the US, every state has its own rules for collecting and reporting taxes.  A previous employer of mine ran into this; we'd had a few people who'd had to move away from the local office for family reasons and we were able to keep them on as remote employees, and then we had one moving to a state where we couldn't meet the tax laws without setting up an in-state office (his house didn't count).  I don't know the details, specifically whether this was a case of "not possible" or "too expensive", but both are reasons that a company might decline to support a particular location.

Also, as noted by Richard U in a comment, commuter taxes can play a part. Further, regulations can have an effect, as some states may have different employment laws, such as mandatory overtime if you work more than "X" hours (Nevada, for example).

It could also be related to supplying health insurance.  I know that my multi-location company offers the same types of health insurance to everybody, *but* the local implementation varies because not all companies offer plans in all states.  So that could be a factor too.

Comment: not enough for an answer, but to supplement yours.  Commuter taxes can play a part as well.  Also, regulations can have an effect, as some states may have different employment laws, such as mandatory overtime if you work more than "X" hours (Nevada, for example).

Answer (score 4):

If it is an Insurance company, there are licencing and other regulations and restrictions that require anyone who works with their clients to be in a licenced location.  So if the company is licenced to provide policies in those states then it could employ workers in those states.

It could also be those are the locations where they already have resources and would be able to easily comply with employment requirements.  Different states have different requirements for reporting and legal requirements.  Anytime you have an employee in a location you expose yourself to litigation in that jurisdiction. They could already have the assets in place to deal with that in those states or it could be those are the states where they have laws that are beneficial to their business practices.

To find out the exact reason you should probably ask that question of the employer, or an agency that provides recruitment services for them.